# Android Preference Textview Multiline?

Tags: android, textview, multiline, preference

How can i use a Textview (Multiline) at a PreferenceActivity?

I found a sample at the app "K-9 Mail". There the preference "signature" is using a textview with multiline.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/) example. Multiline TextView is still the TextView we know, you just need to set the dimensions or print your text with "\n" newline character.

Comment: Thx, but there's no example to do that. I can't upload a screenshot to show you the sample from "K-9 Mail". There they are using directly a textview instead of a EditTextPreference with dialog.

Comment: Uppss .. yes, found the sourcecode. Thx!(Not really easy to use a textview ..)